# Python barcode scanner buffer is not clearing

Tags: python, windows, keyboard, stdin

OS is Windows 7 x64 (running Python x86) but code needs to be exportable to Windows XP and Ubuntu Linux.

This part of the problem is Windows 7 x64 specific, possibly.

I am using a USB barcode scanner that is HID Keyboard compatible.

I open a command prompt in the folder where my keyboard.py file exists and execute it.

It works perfectly the first time and exits, OK.

When I rerun in the same window the scanner data appears to be buffered and no longer changes when new scans are made.

I've tried closing the code using:

```
.flush() .readline() and .read() all to no avail. Is this a flaw in Win7 or am I missing something.
```

CODE:

```
import sys

x = ''
oStr = ''
#while x != 'exit':
while True:
    x = sys.stdin.read(1)
    if (x.find('\n') != -1) or (x.find('\04') != -1):
        break

    oStr = oStr + x


print 'Output String: ' + oStr #+ '\n'


Output:
```

> D:\Python Projects\Keyboard Input>keyboard.py
>   [)>0617V33SR41P12973001S10515725
>   Output String: [)>0617V33SR41P12973001S10515725
>
> D:\Python Projects\Keyboard Input>keyboard.py
>   [)>0617V33SR41P12973001S10515725

The second run stalls, as shown. But, the second scan ended with 23 not 25!

If I press <kbd>Enter</kbd> the script completes. Further scans are the same.

Comment: try sys.stdin.readline().strip() instead of parsing stdin yourself. I think that should give you the result you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

To clarify my previous comment, start with this:

```
while 1:
  print sys.stdin.readline.strip()
```

This should give you a barcode per trigger press. If this works and then running the program sequentially fails you need to look at how your barcode scanner is configured (and this would be a windows configuration issue, not a python issue).

---

**Update:** windows console displayed some weirdness in console which you can workaround by using msvcrt.getch(), however this is not a cross platform solution. One possible approach to making this cross platform would be something like:

```
try:
  from msvcrt import getch
except:
  import sys
  getch = lambda: sys.stdin.read(1)
```

Where you would then program against getch() for reading input.

Comment: Even adding .flush() inside the while gives this:

D:\Python Projects\Keyboard Input>keyboard.py
[)>0617V33SR41P12973001S10515723
[)>0617V33SR41P12973001S10515723
[)>0617V33SR41P12973001S10515723

I get the first two lines after one scan. The third line trying to add a different scan. And, there after no further input is captured.
An [Enter] from the keyboard gives a fourth line. After which additional input is again blocked. If I move focus to Notepad I get the correct scan data.
If I move back to the Command Window the scan data is unchanged.

Weird!

Comment: msvcrt.getch() fixes one problem and creates another that I am not quite sure how to describe. But, the powers that be do not want to use code that requires a bunch of switches and differences when going from Windows to Linux and back. A pyQT lineedit in a popup with a timeout works great, but, again, the powers that be deprecated that solution. I think they will end up capitulating before it's over. :) Thanks! BTW each of three Data Matrix scanners we have send slightly different variations of the same code. Hence my attempt to parse chars one by one.

Comment: See my update above, I hope it may help with your portability issues.